# Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: database, date, array

I'm trying to format the DB timestamp to 'm:d:y`, something like` 07/06/20`. Please change the piece of code below to help achieve it.

```
    echo $dbh->Record['fulfillmentDate']; Returns 2020-07-02 02:38:38
    $date_string = $dbh->Record['fulfillmentDate'];
    $fulfillment_date = date("m.d.y", $date_string); //Error is around this line.
    echo "Fulfillment Date: ". $fulfillment_date;
```

Comment: try to mktime function like :- `mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),date("d"),date("y"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try this Code

```
<?php

$date=date_create($dbh->Record['fulfillmentDate']);

$fomated_date =  date_format($date,"d/m/y");

echo $fomated_date;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$date_string = "2020-07-02 02:38:38"; // $dbh->Record['fulfillmentDate'];
$fulfillment_date = date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_string);
echo date("m.d.y", $fulfillment_date->getTimestamp());
```

Hope it will help.

Thanks.